# how to use results from first query in second query

Tags: mysqli

Ive been reading about mysqli multi_query and couldnt find a way to do this (if its possible)

```
$db->multi_query("SELECT id FROM table WHERE session='1'; 
               UPDATE table SET  last_login=NOW() WHERE id=table.id");
```

It doesnt seem to work. I am trying to use the id of the first query to update the second. is this possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE table 
    SET    last_login = NOW()
    WHERE  id IN (SELECT  id
                  FROM    table2
                  WHERE   session = '1')
```

That will update all your records with session = '1'. Assuming of course that the subquery returns more than one result set, which from what I can see, it will.

This also allows you to drop the `multi_query()` method, as it's just a single query.

---

**In response to the comment:**

According to http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/219882 this doesn't appear to be possible with MySQL. Although I suppose you could go for something like:

```
$db->multiquery(
    "UPDATE table 
         SET    last_login = NOW()
         WHERE  id IN (SELECT  id
                       FROM    table2
                       WHERE   session = '1');
     SELECT id
     FROM   table2
     WHERE  session = '1';"
 );
```

Which is ugly, performing the same query twice, but should do what you want.

Comment: is there a way to rewrite it so that I can get the result set back and use it lower in the script.. thats what im after. just wondering if i have placed with 2 queries that can be turned into one.